# Trouble installing PECL YAML package

Tags: php, yaml

I'm trying the YAML package for PHP 7.1, and can't quite seem to get it working.

I tried the following commands:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libyaml-dev
$ sudo pecl install yaml
```

When I run the pecl install, I get:

```
fatal error: ext/standard/php_smart_string.h: No such file or directory
```

The only results I can find when I try googling are a version issue, but according to them make output, its trying to install 2.0.2, which is the latest version? I can't find out much on this.

Answer (score 0):

`php_smart_string.h` is part of the `php7.1-dev` package. You have to install that first.

Try `apt-file search php_smart_string.h` whenever you are getting such an error, it helps you to locate in which package the file can be.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I ended up finding out there was an apt-get package for php7.1-yaml, and that seems to have worked. I will test with php7.1-dev, as I'd like to learn where I went wrong.